# Unity3D WebGL build not calling Update

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the weirdest problem. Update and FixedUpdate are not getting called for one object and only in the WebGL build. Running in the editor works, iOS works and Android works.
I upgraded to the latest version of Unity3D 2017 to see if that would fix the issue or throw an exception that I'm missing but no luck.

Has anyone experienced anything like this before?

```
public class NewLives : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI text;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log("Update");
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Debug.Log("FixedUpdate");
        text.SetText(GameController.GameData.GetLives().ToString());
    }
}
```

Update: I found that Start doesn't get called either which is why Update isn't getting called. This would of course mean that the object isn't active but I never set it to inactive.

Comment: I doubt what you said in your question is true, `Update` is likely being called but there is an error somewhere. Maybe `text.SetText`, `GameController.GameData` or  `GameController.GameData.GetLives` is null. I would ask you to use a simple `Text` component to test this in the `Update` and `Update` function by writing to it a static value such as 5 and 9.

Comment: I tried creating a new script. I tried using a standard Text component, I added a check for null and write that out instead but nothing seems to work in the WebGL build. It doesn't make sense, I know but this just doesn't want to work. I added some more info.

Comment: Do the following:1. Write a script that uses 3 `Text` components. Change each Text in the `Start`, `Update` `FixedUpdate` functions and  then update your question with that script. I just need to see it. 2.Select the GameObject the `NewLives` script is attached to and take a screenshot of the Inspector tab then post it in your question. This will help me see what's going on here.

Comment: Well... I don't know what the issue was but I kicked off a cloud build instead of locally building and it works now. I don't like problems like these...